# Azure API Gateway and authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

We are looking to publish an `API` in an `Azure B2C` model where customers will use our app to access API's published using `Docker Swarm` based `Azure Container Services`. Our assumption here is that this model will require `Azure B2C AD` as opposed to Azure AD.

All API calls will have an `OAuth` token issued from B2C AD.

We want to know what is the best approach to validate the token centrally before it reaches the microservices on `Azure Container Service`. We were using `API Gateway` to route the API calls to the correct microservice while also using the `WAF` capability in the `API Gateway`. However, we realize that the API Gateway does not provide a way to verify the `OAuth` token before it forwards the request to the microservices.

Also please note, as per the suggestions in `Microsoft Documentation` we have two tenants with one tenant running all services such as database and microservice and the second tenant hosting the Azure B2C AD.

Can you please suggest the best option to implement the `OAuth Verification` without having to implement this in each microservice.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is put Azure API Management Service between your clients and services, there you'd have an option to use validate-jwt policy to inspect tokens and authorize calls.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a quick overview of the steps:

1. Register an application (backend-app) in Azure AD to represent the API.
2. Register another application (client-app) in Azure AD to represent a client application that needs to call the API.
3. In Azure AD, grant permissions to allow the client-app to call the backend-app.
4. Configure the Developer Console to call the API using OAuth 2.0 user authorization.
5. Add the validate-jwt policy to validate the OAuth token for every incoming request.

Please refer to the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) for steps in detail.